# Any special assertion to test if the resulting integer lies within a range

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I would like to test if an instance variable lies in a range of numbers:

```
#part of the tested class
class Item
  def initialize(value = 70 + rand(30))
    @value = value
  end
```

I tried the assertions in [minitest assertions list](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Assertions.html) but they didn't work. I solved the problem by using assert_in_delta as shown below:

```
#test_value.rb
class ValueTestCase < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_if_value_in_range
    item = Item.new
    assert_in_delta(85, item.value, 15)
  end
end
```

But would like to know if there is a formal assertion for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way would be to use `Range#include?`:

```
assert_includes 70..100, p.value
```

Comment: @barerd: The API docs are at http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/. `assert_includes` is defined in `Minitest::Assertions`, but I can't find `assert_contains`. The link in your question also lists `assert_includes`.

Comment: Well, [http://docs.seattlerb.org/](http://docs.seattlerb.org/) is a certainly better doc the one I found. Thank you for that.

Comment: I prefer this solution because it gives a more useful failure message

Answer (score 9):

```
assert(item.value.between?(70, 100))
```

Comment: This is better than Niklas's answer as it works on floats as well

Answer (score 0):

assert((min..max) === result)

Works with Test::Unit.